# If a quantum algorithm requires a measurement, how can we use that as a subroutine in another quantum algorithm?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, unitarity

Some algorithms (like period finding), use one or more measurement step. The post measurement state is then acted upon by another set of gates to complete the algorithm.
If I imagine this as blackbox algorithm $f$ which takes $x$ as input and computes $f(x)$; then one can write a corresponding quantum circuit and use it as a subroutine in another quantum algorithm (like Grover's).

Now if one wants to implement this in a circuit, doesn't the measurement operation hiding inside $f$ create an issue of a possibly exponential number of measurements (like in Grover where we construct the full superposition)? I read somewhere that a CPTP operation can be embedded in a larger space as a unitary, but I recall it as an existence result. But even if that larger circuit has a construction, can't complexity/size of that circuit be much bigger?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to QCSE.  Often for  theoretical reasons within the gate model, we appeal to the [deferred measurement principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Measurement_Principle) to say that we can wait to have all measurements at the end of the circuit.  We just imagine moving to a larger and larger Hilbert space while we postpone our measurements.

For example, if a circuit proposes to measure a single-qubit register *in-situ*, and then perform various operations based on the results of the measurement (e.g. whether it's $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$), we can always rewrite that circuit so that the measurement is done at the end.  By doing this, our Hilbert space may be doubled in size.

Other models such as [one-way quantum computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_quantum_computer) are a bit trickier to visualize, because there the measurements and post-measurement gates applied drive the calculation. But nonetheless the deferred measurement principle still applies.

Note that *in-situ* measurements and post-measurement actions are done during [quantum error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction) and I haven't thought too much about the deferred measurement principle in the context of QEC, but still we can always pray at the church of the higher Hilbert space.

Comment: I feel like the answer changes a bit depending on the algorithm one has in mind though. In cases such as Grover or Deuthsc, one is not actually using a "subroutine" in the same sense you would classically, because the function implemented by the oracle, even though it does "solve a problem" when fed classical states, is used in a rather different way in the quantum algorithm, being fed with superpositions. In particular, you don't need to "measure its output" for the overall algorithm to work.